# Enforcing smoothness constraint techniques

Tags: optimization, smooth-manifolds, image-processing

I have the following values

```
2 4 5 6 20 30 40 50
```

I have another table where for each of these values i i have anothe set of values

For value 2 , I have `3,20,40`
For value 4 , I have `60,3,10`
For value 5, I have `12,15,3`

What I need to try to find is the value which is most uniform for the given values within a given window

In the above case, I would have to choose 3 for (2,4,5) , since it is present in value 2,4,5 .

If for value 4, I had 60,4,10, then for (2,4,5) my value would be (3,4,3)

What is a good technique to ensure smoothness to find something like this?

Any keyword or pointers I should be looking for? The exact value may not be present but it should be close(smooth and should not be abrupt)